# SAS - Reference One Dimension of a Multi-Dimension Array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, sas

I have a macro which accepts a 1-dimensional array as a parameter. I would like to pass it one dimension of a 2D array, but I can't figure out how to reference one full dimension of a 2D array cleanly to produce a new one-dimensional array. I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing but I can't find it.

Below is some test code I wrote to try and reference one dimension of "myVals."

```
data test;
   array myVals {3,4} myVal1_1 - myVal1_4
                      myVal2_1 - myVal2_4
                      myVal3_1 - myVal3_4;
   do i = 1 to 3;
      do j = 1 to 4;
         myVals{i,j} = j - i + 3;
      end;
   end;

   array newArray {*} myVals{1}; *All of these throw errors;
   array newArray {*} myVals[1];
   array newArray {*} myVals(1);
   array newArray {*} myVals{1,};

   len2ndDim = dim2(myVals); *this produces a column with value 4;

   array newArray {len2ndDim}; *this throws error for "len2ndDim" not being an integer constant or *;
run;
```

***EDIT FOR TOM's COMMENT***
I would like to be able to create a named array newArray which, depending on whether a data step loop variable is 1,2 or 3, would alias to either:

- variables myval1_1 - myVal1_4 OR
- variables myVal2_1 - myVal2_4 OR
- variables myVal3_1 - myVal3_4

then I would call myMacro which takes three params - name, start index, end index. I would make these calls like:

- myMacro(newArray, 1, myEndIndex1) , or
- myMacro(newArray, 1, myEndIndex2)

Comment: Why?  Remember that the ARRAY statement is just defining an alias you can use to refer to multiple variables, it is not actually creating a data structure that is an array.

Comment: Hi Tom, I would like an alias to use to be able to pass a certain dimension of a 2D array to a macro which accepts a 1D array.

Comment: How are you currently passing the array as a parameter? How do you see passing it one dimension?  Do you mean that you want to pass it a number and interpret that number as the index for one of the dimensions of the array?  If so why not just reference the macro variable in the array reference in the DATA step code?  `myvals[&dim1,K]`

Comment: I have variables like myVal1_1 through myVal3_4 as above. I have a data step loop of N from 1-3 (the first dimension of my defined 2D array) and for each N 1,2 and 3, I would like to call a macro passing ..N_1, ...N_2, ...N_3 and ...N_4 to a macro. The macro accepts the name of an array and start/end indices. So if I could make a new array alias out of the Nth dimension of my 2D array, I could pass that array name to this macro. passing myvals[&dim1,K] passes one value at a time but I want to pass an array name that can do logic on many variables.

Comment: Can you post an example? I am not seeing how the macro parameters relate to the data step code you want the macro to generate.  If I want to pass multiple values to a macro, then I normally do that as a space delimited list. So if I have a parameter named `LIST` I can call the macro with `LIST=1 3 6 7`. I can then use `%sysfunc(countw(&list))` to find out that `4` values were passed.

Comment: updated the question with an example of how I would call the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DIM2 function solved my issue. I want to cleanly reference one dimension of a 2D array without using a macro %do loop to loop through variable name (as discussed in comments on Robert Penridge's answer)s. Here's how to use DIM2 to do it referencing only datastep vars.

```
data test;
   array myVals {3,4} myVal1_1 - myVal1_4
                      myVal2_1 - myVal2_4
                      myVal3_1 - myVal3_4;

   array slice {4} slice_1 - slice_4;

   do i = 1 to 3;
       do j = 1 to DIM2{myVals};
          slice{j} = myVals{i,j}; 
          %do_calculations_on(input1Darray=slice, inputArrayLength=4}
       end;
   end;
run;
```

The method above would also allow slicing of the another dimension, by reversing the order of the i,j loops

```
array diff_slice {3} diff_slice1 - diff_slice3;
do j = 1 to 4;
   do i = 1 to DIM1{myVals}; *DIM1 is DIM, or 3 in this case;
      diff_slice{i} = myVals{i, j}
      %do_calculations_on_(input1Darray=diff_slice, inputArrayLength=3);
   end;
end;
```

As people have mentioned before, "passing an array" to my macro really just means passing a string that represents a common prefix for a list of variables. Still, the method above allows me to define a new set of commonly-prefix'd variables to pass (slice or diff_slice) which represent any slice of any dimension of a multidimension array, using data step vars without having to rely on macro do loops and initial array names organized in a certain way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to select one of the 3 dimensions that contains 4 values you can reference it like so:

```
array newArray [*] myVal2: ;
```

This is because your original array statement is creating the variables named `myVal2_1, ... myVal2_4`.  All the statement above is doing is using wildcard syntax to place every variable that begins with 'myVal2' into a new array.

If your array has more complex names this approach would not work.  You'll need to seek more complex solutions.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the prompt reply. In my real use case, I need myVal1: or myVal2: or myVal3: depending on my value of of a datastep var looping through 1-3 (dimension of my first level). So I think I can use your solution, but only if I change that loop var to a macro variable so I'd have something like myVal&loopVar.: . Although I need that loop variable to be a datastep var in other places. I'll keep thinking. Thanks again.

Comment: If you want to define array like objects where the dimension is unknown until run-time you can use the hash object.  If you explain more about what you want and what you need I or someone else might be able to help.

Comment: @MaxPower Yes - you would need to macro-ise the suffix based on what you described.  Alternatively, if performance is a factor, then the hash object would be a better approach as data _null_ recommends.

Comment: So...using call symput() to move my datastep loop var to a macro var didn't work for me. I ended up with the old error of invoking the macro var (at macro execution) before call symput creates it (at program execution). To fix that I'd usually create a new data step to invoke the created macro variable. But in this case that doesn't work because in a new data step I lose all my array assignments. Reading up on hash objects now.

Comment: Epilogue...call symput was unnecessary. Just changed the do loop to a %do loop. I still prefer to use data step vara instead of macro vars when possible, but this was workable.

Comment: Epilogue 2 - if anyone's interested this came up again for me in another program and I found a way to do this without resorting to a macro %do loop inside a data step. I posted the solution as an answer to the question on this page.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not understanding what the issue really is here. 
If you want the flexibility to generate an `ARRAY` statement like:

```
array myVals {3,4} myVal1_1 myVal1_4 myVal2_1-myVal2_4 myVal3_1 myVal3_4;
```

Then you want to use three parameters:

```
%macro my2dmacro (basename=,dim1=,dim2=);
   %local i ;
array &basename.s {&dim1,&dim2}
    %do i=1 %to &dim1; &basename.&i._1-&basename.&i._&dim2 %end;
;
%mend my2dmacro;
```

So then if you call it with these values:

```
%my2dmacro(basename=myval,dim1=3,dim2=4);
```

It will generate this statement:

```
array myvals {3,4} myval1_1-myval1_4 myval2_1-myval2_4 myval3_1-myval3_4;
```

When you want to request a 1-D array you could instead use something like this:

```
%macro my1dmacro (basename=,dim1=,dim2=);
array &basename.&dim1.s {&dim2} &basename.&dim1._1-&basename.&dim1._&dim2;
%mend my1dmacro;
```

If you call it with these values:

```
%my1dmacro(basename=myval,dim1=3,dim2=4);
```

It will generate this statement.

```
array myval3s {4} myval3_1-myval3_4;
```

You could combine them into a single macro and use another parameter to allow the user to specify which form of an ARRAY statement to generate.